# Column Combination parameter

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sqlparameter

Why I got error with this? Or is it possible to have a query like this?

```
select Employee.EmployeeID, Employee.LastName + ', ' + Employee.FirstName + ' ' + Employee.MiddleName as EmployeeFullName
From Employee
Where EmployeeFullName = 'someFullName'
```

Invalid column name 'EmployeeFullName'.

Comment: please post error also

Comment: because you are trying to retrive value from nonexistent column. You should create that one and retrive  values after this.

Comment: `AuthorFullName`, `EmployeeFullName`? Typo?

Comment: Yes just a typo. I edit it

Comment: It is not a computed column. It is a combination of nvarchar columns.

Answer (score 0):

May be error occurred because any of `field`(`lastname, firstname,middlename`) may be `null` 
Try this

```
select 
Employee.EmployeeID, 
isnull(Employee.LastName,'') + ', ' + isnull(Employee.FirstName,'') + ' ' + isnull(Employee.MiddleName,'') as EmployeeFullName
From Employee
Where AuthorFullName = 'someFullName'
```

Edit 1)

your where condition is wrong that's why you got (Invalid column name 'AuthorFullName'. )this error.

Edit 2)

```
select 
    Employee.EmployeeID, 
    isnull(Employee.LastName,'') + ', ' + isnull(Employee.FirstName,'') + ' ' + isnull(Employee.MiddleName,'') as EmployeeFullName
    From Employee
    Where isnull(Employee.LastName,'') + ', ' + isnull(Employee.FirstName,'') + ' ' + isnull(Employee.MiddleName,'') = 'someFullName'
```

Comment: authorfullname is not an existing column that's why you get this error

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT FullName FROM 
( 
    SELECT 
        FullName = LastName + ', ' + FirstName + ' ' + MiddleName
        FROM Employee  
) sub 
WHERE sub.FullName = 'someFullName'
```